# FindControl for nested controls in UserControl returns null

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, findcontrol

I have a very weird issue. I have a UserControl that has some controls inside. I want to refer those controls after, in another postback. But when I try to get them the `Controls` property of my controls returns null.
I'm working on vs2008.

Here is the sample code:

```
public partial class MyUserControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl, INamingContainer
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Control control in this.Controls)
        {
            Response.Write(control.ClientID);
        }
    }

    private void MyTable()
    {
        Table table = new Table();
        TableRow row = new TableRow();
        TableCell cell = new TableCell();

        CheckBox check = new CheckBox();
        check.ID = "theId";
        check.Text = "My Check";
        check.AutoPostBack = true;
        cell.Controls.Add(check);
        row.Cells.Add(cell);

        check = new CheckBox();
        check.ID = "theOther";
        check.AutoPostBack = true;
        check.Text = "My Other Check";

        cell = new TableCell();
        cell.Controls.Add(check);
        row.Cells.Add(cell);

        table.Rows.Add(row);
        this.Controls.Add(table);
    }

    protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        MyTable();
        base.Render(writer);
    }
}
```

and the Default.aspx page is something like:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.cs" Inherits="Tester.Default" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="uc1" TagName="MyControl" Src="~/MyUserControl.ascx" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title>Unbenannte Seite</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <uc1:MyControl ID="MyControlInstance" runat="server" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't know if I'm lost in some part of the ASP.NET life cycle. But this situation is making me crazy. Any help would be very grateful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create your child controls (`MyTable`) in either `CreateChildControls` or `OnInit`:

```
protected override void CreateChildControls()
{
    MyTable();
    base.CreateChildControls();
}
```

Or

```
protected override void OnInit(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    MyTable();
    base.OnInit(e);
}
```

You shouldn't/cannot create controls in `Render` as it occurs after `Page_Load`. See the ASP.Net Page Lifecycle [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx).

Comment: You´re right. Now I want to ask you. The Table should be created everytime the page does postbacks? or there is a way to keep it in memory to handle it later.

Comment: You should recreate it every time.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is because the `Render` event occurs after `Page_Load`, so when you are trying to iterate your control collection, it hasn't been set up yet. Most common solution is to override `CreateChildControls` to get the proper timing down.